# Add string from TextSwitcher to array

Tags: android, arrays, string

I want to put the currently displayed string from [`TextSwitcher`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextSwitcher.html) (string is placed in one's string array) to other string array and I don't know which method should I do because `.getText` doesn`t work for textSwitcher.

How to load and add string to existing but not using in this Activity string array?

I found this method on internet, why it doesn't work ?

```
Resources res = getResources();
String[] favorites = res.getStringArray(R.array.favorites);
String[] planets = res.getStringArray(R.array.planets_array);
String[] temp = new String[favorites.length+1];
System.arraycopy(favorites,0,temp,0,favorites.length);
temp[favorites.length] = planets[mCounter];
favorites = temp;
```

Answer (score 3):

`TextSwitcher` is implemented as container with two `TextViews`. When you call `TextSwitcher.setText()`, it will call `TextView.setText()` on the TextView that is not showing and then switch between them with an optional animation.

Although TextSwitcher does not expose a `getText()` method, it is possible to retrieve the currently shown `TextView` child and then call `getText()` on it to get the text that is displayed:

```
TextSwitcher textSwitcher = findViewById(...);
TextView currentlyShownTextView = (TextView) textSwitcher.getCurrentView();
String currentlyShownText = textSwitcher.getText().toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

[`TextSwitcher`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextSwitcher.html) does not provide a `getText` method. So you have to remember the current string in a private field everytime you call `setText`.

```
class MyActivity extends Activity {
    String currentlyDisplayedText;
    String[] yourArray = new String[5];

    public void someMethod() {
        currentlyDisplayedText = "The new text";
        theTextSwitcher.setText(currentlyDisplayedText);
    }

    public void someOtherMethod() {
        yourArray[0] = currentlyDisplayedText;
    }
}
```